# sqlite insert into fails

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi I'm new to python and going through some tutorials, my code doesn't give any errors but it fails, the full list of problems are at the bottom

here's my first .py file which is rehber.py

```
import crehber

print("ASIM's Contact List")

print("To create a Table press 1")
print("To write into database press 2")

choice = int(input("Your Choice: "))

def checkInput(choice):

    if choice == 1:
        print("Your Choice is ", choice)
        crehber.tablecreate()
        return True
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Your Choice is ", choice)
        name = str(input("Enter name: "))
        surname = str(input("Enter surname: "))
        number = int(input("Enter number: "))
        crehber.tableInsert(name,surname,number)
        return True
    else:
        print("Invalid choice, please re-enter")

while checkInput(choice) != True:
    choice = int(input("Your Choice: "))
```

and here is the other .py file which is crehber.py

```
import sqlite3 as db

def tablecreate():
    conn = db.connect('rehber.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('create table bilgiler(name text,sname text, num text)')
    print("Table is created")

def tableInsert(name,surname,number):
    conn = db.connect('rehber.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('insert into bilgiler(name,sname,num) values(?,?,?)', (name,surname,number))
    print("Insert is Successful")
    conn.close()
```

Additional Information:

1-) sqlite is in c:\sqlite
2-) I created a directory c:\pythonb to play with, this is where my .py files are

Problems List & Questions:

1- When in sqlite directory and I type in sqlite3 rehber.db, the file is created there.
then when I run the program and call the

```
tableCreate() function
```

rehber.db appears in the  pythonb directory, is this normal?

2- When I make some entries and get "Insert is successful" message
I go to sqlite directory and type in sqlite3 rehber.db 
then select * from bilgiler;
but nothing appears.. what do you think is wrong?

3- I sometimes miss the semicolon ; after the select command and I get stuck in the sqlite shell, how can I quit without closing commandprompt?

Thanks for sparing your time in reading, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> 1- When in sqlite directory and I type in sqlite3 rehber.db, the file is created there. then when I run the program and call the `tableCreate()` function rehber.db appears in the pythonb directory, is this normal?

I don't know about "normal", but when you just specify a file without any pathname—in any program at all—you get a file in the current working directory. So, if you open a DOS prompt, `cd c:\sqlite` and then run `sqlite3 rehber.db`, that will create a file `c:\sqlite\rehber.db`, because `c:\sqlite` is your current working directory. And if you open a DOS prompt, `cd c:\pythonb`, and `rehber.py`, this will create a file `c:\pythonb\rehber.db`, because `c:\pythonb` is your current working directory.

> 2- When I make some entries and get "Insert is successful" message I go to sqlite directory and type in sqlite3 rehber.db then select * from bilgiler; but nothing appears.. what do you think is wrong?

Well, one program (your script) is operating on one file, another (`sqlite3`) is operating on a completely different file. Nothing appears for the same reason that when you fill up your car's gas tank nothing appears in my car's gas tank.

> 3- I sometimes miss the semicolon ; after the select command and I get stuck in the sqlite shell, how can I quit without closing commandprompt?

You can just enter the semicolon on the continuation prompt line (the `...>`) to finish the last command.

Comment: I don't get any output when I run the rehber.db in pythonb neither.. shall I copy rehber.db from sqlite directory to pythonb directory then run the program?